# Would it be possible to create a wood/metal texture only using nodes, not texture images?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am looking for a creative way to get around loading texture map files to create materials that look like wood/metal. Basically, I wonder if it would be possible to connect the material/texture nodes in a way that they can naturally output wood/metal like texture maps. Does anyone know if that could be possible?

Here's my try to make a metal texture:

Original:

[image]

After connecting the noise texture node:

[image]

And here's another example:

Original:
[image]

After connecting the noise texture node:
[image]

Here's my try for making a **wood** texture:

Original:
[image]

After connecting the noise texture node:
[image]

However, for **metal** I would like to be able to connect the nodes to be able to get something like this:

[image]

And for **wood** I would like to be able to get something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Does anyone know how can one do such texturing only via nodes and without using image textures? Would love to see your solutions :)

Comment: They keyword is "procedural wood". There are many tutorials around and even free materials on blendswap (https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/84699)

Comment: yeah, this is called procedural texturing. i will link some videos so you can learn how to make those.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWrbskgppHM&t=824s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4BhdrFDHkQ

search for more videos and learn and you will be able to make procedural textures on your own

Comment: CGMasters has a [couple of good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSB-v4upJzI) procedural [texture tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiJZKqbfFgQ). There is also a nice wood texture with explanation [here](https://materialw.wordpress.com/materials/wood-material/)